# sending data to MVC from an angular post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

We are using angularjs to post a form to an MVC controller to process

```
$scope.resultsFilter = function () {
    $scope.data = [];
    $scope.data = {
        startdate: $scope.$$childHead.resultfilter.startdate,
        enddate: $scope.$$childHead.resultfilter.enddate,
        frequency: $scope.resultfilter.frequency,
        direction: $scope.resultfilter.direction
    };

    var url = '/user/GetResults/';
    $http.post(url, $scope.data).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                     if (data.msg != '') {
                         $scope.msgs.push(data.msg);
                     }
                     else {
                         $scope.errors.push(data.error);
                     }
                 }).error(function (data, status) { // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                     // or server returns response with an error status.
                     $scope.errors.push(status);
                 });

};
});
```

and the MVC controller is :-

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetResults()
    {

    }
```

how do we access the data that has been posted by the form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have POCO equivalent of that data, something like:

```
public class MyData{
  public DateTime startdate{get;set;}
  public DateTime enddate{get;set;}
  ....
}
```

You can try:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetResults(MyData myData)
{

}
```

With the following HTTP Post:

```
$http({
     url: '/controllerName/GetResults/',
     method: "POST",
     data:$scope.data,
   })
   .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

   }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

});
```

Comment: That works, however, is there a way to access it without creating a class just to pass data to a controller?

Comment: Well if you step back and look at what you're trying to do, creating a class is the cleanest way possible. I mean you could inspect the body of the request and extract the data manually, but that's a lot more hassle, better take advantage of MVC's model binder.

Comment: If you really wanted to not create a seperate class, you could use the `FormCollection` class I suppose..

Answer (score 0):

> you can get MVC model using model object and pass to function as json
>   data

```
click=someFunc('@Json.Encode(Model)');
```